# MKDirections multiple locations xcode 6.2 Mapkit

Tags: xcode, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am using xcode beta 6.2. It shouldn't matter as my question is in relation to the  API's - specifically calling MKDirections with MKDirectionsRequest's.

Please note there is one other similar question posted to this forum, that does not provide a solution: [iOS MKDirections for multiple destinations and a single source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104337/ios-mkdirections-for-multiple-destinations-and-a-single-source)

**My Problem:**

- I have a set of MKMapItem's held in a custom object class.
- This set of MKMapItem's will only ever reach between 1-5 records. Each of these items represent a destination for which I want to calculate the Estimated Time of Arrival for, from the user's current location.

In effect, I want to wrap the following statement in a loop, and then wait for the call back to finish before calling the next destination. Note that the API will not allow simultaneous requests:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = 40.71278371;
location.longitude = -74.0059413;

MKPlacemark* placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location addressDictionary:nil];

MKMapItem* destinationMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];

MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
[request setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];
[request setDestination:destinationMapItem];
[request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile]; 
[request setRequestsAlternateRoutes:NO];
MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[directions calculateETAWithCompletionHandler:^(MKETAResponse *response, NSError *error)
 {
     NSString *eta = [Utils stringFromTimeInterval:response.expectedTravelTime];

     NSLog(@"ETA route1: %@", eta);
 }];
```

Can somebody kindly suggest an example of how to loop through an object and do this. I know this may risk throttling from the service, however my mate was able to achieve this on an android build of our product. I should hopefully be able to hit the services for between 1-5 destinations.

Thanking you in advance. I couldn't add tags of MKDirections or MKDirections request. If anyone else can that would be great!

Simon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop and create an `MKDirectionsRequest` for each destination in your set (or array). As each completion handler block gets called, store the result in a set or (array). I have sent multiple requests 'rapid fire' like this to get directions and have not been throttled.

Comment: thanks but don't you get an error message back from the API's saying that you cannot call the service at the same time (while another directions request is being processed?) How do I stop the loop from recursing while the first service is being processed by the apple directions server?

Comment: I have called an `MKDirectionsRequest` ten times inside a loop and received a result for each. Apple isn't going to deny your request, but will throttle (slow down) the results at a certain unpublished threshold. Are you doing hundreds at a time?

Comment: thanks - agreed.... appreciate your help.... please upvote my questions... need to be able to vote on this site!